# Work to compress vapour vs that to compress liquid

Tags: thermodynamics

I am looking over a thermodynamics text and it is said that:

> the work input required to compress a liquid is significantly
>   less that that required to compress a vapour

Is this really the case? I have always thought that it required less force to compress a gas than a liquid (compressed air is common, compressed water not so much) and therefore the work required to do so would be greater for liquid than a vapour.

Can anyone offer an explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly are you varying when you compress the substance? If you are applying the same change in volume, then yes the work done to compress the liquid will be far higher.

If, however, you are applying the same change in pressure the volume of the gas will change a great deal, but the volume of the liquid will barely change at all. Changing the external pressure in the same way for both cases, the external forces on both will be the same, so the only thing effecting the amount of work done will be the change in volume and more work will be done on the gas.